# Bird's Nest, Birds' Nest, or Birds Nest?

Tags: grammar, names

If I had to name a store selling bird houses from the three following options, which one would sound the most appropriate?

- Bird's Nest
- Birds' Nest
- Birds Nest

Comment: Birds' nests are rarely occupied by a single bird, so my suggestion would be - *birds' nest.*

Comment: All three are said the same way; apostrophes are silent.

Comment: If you are selling bird houses, perhaps 'Nest' should be plural?

Comment: From a marketing perspective rather than a language one (because all three would be appropriate) Birds' [bird-sis] sounds the most awkward, no?

Comment: Why not call it "The Bird Nest"

Comment: @faraza didn't know it pronounces that way, valid point, it would be a pain for people to pronounce it.

Comment: @michael_timofeev because it's an online store and TheBirdNest.com is taken.

Comment: I think I'm just going to brand it as Birdsnest in one word.

Comment: @LyesD Well, that's a bummer...I kinda liked that option...Thebirdhouse.com is still available.

Comment: @LyesD  I like Birdsnest.

Answer (score 0):

They all have different meanings.

> Bird's Nest means "the nest of a (single) bird."
>
> Birds' Nest means "the nest of some number of birds."
>
> Birds Nest means exactly that, "birds (do) nest," with nest as a verb.

For simplicity's sake, and considering it is going to be the name of a store and people will inevitably mess it up anyway and you'll have to constantly correct everyone, I would go with Birds Nest, which has a subtle double meaning. Birds do nest, and hopefully if you're selling bird-houses, they will nest in those. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Either of the first two would be good, but if people looked at "Birds Nest", they would think you'd forgotten an apostrophe somewhere and had made a grammatical mistake.

"Birds' Nest" or "Bird's Nest" are noun phrases, but "Birds Nest" is not. It's true that it's a grammatical sentence and a true statement (birds do nest), but while it might be cool to have a double meaning, it's not going to be immediately apparent to most people since "birds' nest" or "bird's nest" are such common phrases. "Birds nest" will seem like an error at first glance.

Comment: That's a good point.